# Ruby Instantiate class with 2 parameters

Tags: ruby

Ruby help, where am I going wrong, it works if I just initialize logger:, but if i try to add table_name I am not getting the syntax right, please someone help, point me in the right direction.

```
class Test

     def initialize(logger:, table_name:)
         @ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
         @ddb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new
         @logger = logger
         @table_name = table_name
     end
end

logger = Logger.new(STDERR)
table_name = ENV['ec2_information'].split('/')[1]

discovery = Test.new(logger:, table_name:)
```

Stacktrace

```
"/var/task/test.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected ','\n... 
Test.new(logger:, table_name:)\n...                              ^",
"errorType": "Init<SyntaxError>",
```

Comment: Don't use `:` in both situatuions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to that error and which one you prefer is up to you and the expressiveness you want to achieve.

#### Named parameters

The first one uses named parameters (also called [keyword arguments](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)) which is what you are currently using in your `initialize` method:

```
def initialize(logger:, table_name:)
  ...
end
```

If you want to send such a method, regardless if it is the `new` method or any other method, you also have to do so in a named fashion. In the current example, this would mean

```
Test.new(logger: logger, table_name: table_name)
```

But as the parameters are named, and as such the ordering is unimportant, it could also be

```
Test.new(table_name: table_name, logger: logger)
```

#### Unnamed parameters

The other solution would be to define the method signature without naming the parameters

```
def initialize(logger, table_name) # no colon
  ...
end
```

Given a method signature such as this, the order does matter and you would have to send e.g.

```
Test.new(logger, table_name) # no colon
```

#### Hash parameter

Named parameters are not to be confused with accepting a hash for a parameter. The signature would be:

```
def initialize(hash)
  # do something with hash[:logger] and hash[:table_name]
  ... 
end
```

But the method send would look the same as with named parameters

```
Test.new(logger: logger, table_name: table_name)
```

But that is only due to the interpreter treating it as a hash. You could also send a method in it's canonical form for such a signature

```
Test.new({ logger: logger, table_name: table_name })
```

The same cannot be done for named parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Test.new(logger:, table_name:)`, Ruby-interpretator thinks, that your argument is hash and `:logger` is a key.

So it expects that there should be a value of this key. But instead of that - comma.

That's why syntax error.